Finding a symbol sequence such that the PSD is 0 at certain frequencies
Let $\left\{ C_{n}\right\}  $ be an arbitrary sequence of real numbers(symbols).
Lets denote the Power Spectral Density with some shape filter such that.
$$ \tilde{S}_{d}\left(f\right)=\frac{T}{4}sinc^{4}\left(\frac{T}{2}f\right)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}R_{C}\left(n\right)e^{-2\pi jnfT}$$
Where $$R_C(n) = E\left[C_{m+n}C_{m}\right] $$
Is it possible to find a specific sequence $\{C_n\}$ such that $\forall m\in \mathbb{Z}$ $$ \tilde{S_{d}}\left(f\right)\biggr|_{f=\frac{m}{5T}}=\frac{T}{4}sinc^{4}\left(\frac{T}{2}f\right)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}R_{C}\left(n\right)e^{-2\pi jnfT}\biggr|_{f=\frac{m}{5T}}=0$$
I.E
$$ \frac{T}{4}sinc^{4}\left(\frac{m}{10}\right)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}R_{C}\left(n\right)e^{\frac{-2}{5}\pi jnm}=0\,\forall m\in\mathbb{Z} $$
I tried guessing finite sequences, but I noticed that i need that $ \left|R_{C}\left(0\right)\right|\ge\left|R_{C}\left(n\right)\right|$ and $ R_{C}\left(n\right)=R_{C}\left(-n\right) $
How can I come up with such a sequence $\{C_n\} $ or at least an autocorrelation function $R_C(n)$ that is not $C_n \equiv 0 $ ?
